# Is reference variable and Object created from a class using new keyword in Java, one and the same thing?

Tags: java, object

In java if I have class called Coder and I write like -

```
Coder coder1 = new Coder();
```

then **coder1** is called **reference variabl**e, right? As it is referencing **Coder** class, but why then any **Object** created using new keyword is called Object of that type/class rather than reference variable of that class. Or are both things synonymous. Please clear my doubt!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An object is the thing that holds the values. You create it using `new Coder()`. It has no name.

A reference variable is a thing that *points to* that object. You can think of it as a name that you give it.

If you just create `new Coder()` and never let anything point to it it will be pointless and eventually garbage collected, because there's no way to reference it.

If you do

```
Coder coder1 = new Coder();
```

then `coder1` is a reference to the object. You can use it to call methods on the object like `coder1.toString()`.

You can even create *another* reference that points to the *same* object:

```
Coder coder2 = coder1;
```

It *might look like* you now have 2 `Coder` objects, but you don't. There's still only one. You have 2 references to it (or "names" if you will). `coder1.toString()` will do the exact same thing as `coder2.toString()`, because they reference the same object.

Comment: Ok! got it coder1 is a reference to an Object of class/type Coder which has been created using the new keyword. I was of an opinion that coder1 is also an object which its not. Thank You.

Comment: Note that colloquially people might say things like "the `Coder` object `coder1`", which is **technically** not correct, but universally understood to mean "the `Coder` object that *`coder1` points to*".

Comment: yeah! that's the thing that confuses some like me to think of reference variables as objects! thank you for that comment of yours, cleared my doubt.

Answer (score 0):

You have the Class (Coder), from which you can create objects.
When you use new, you create an object which type is Coder, then this object is allocated a memory space, than new return and store the reference to this object in coder1.